# Replace on column value dependgin on other columns and conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5
G1   NaN  NaN  NaN  A
G1   NaN  Lop  NaN  A 
G2   NaN  NaN  NaN  B 
G3   Sil  NaN  SLO  A
G4   NaN  NaN  NaN  C
G4   LIJ  KYI  NaN  B
```

Then the idea it to replace `COL2` values by `OK` if `COL2,COL3,COL4 == "NaN"` & COL5 is in `list("A","B")`

I should get

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5
G1   OK   NaN  NaN  A
G1   NaN  Lop  NaN  A 
G2   OK  NaN  NaN  B 
G3   Sil  NaN  SLO  A
G4   NaN  NaN  NaN  C
G4   LIJ  KYI  NaN  B
```

So far I tried:

```
tab['COL2'][(tab['COL2'].isna()) & (tab['COL3'].isna()) & (tab['COL4'].isna()) & tab['COL5'].str.contains("A|B"))] = "OK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `all` + `isna`

```
df.loc[df.COL5.isin(['A','B']) & df[['COL2','COL3','COL4']].isna().all(1),'COL2']='OK'
df
Out[22]: 
   COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5
0   G1   OK  NaN  NaN    A
1   G1  NaN  Lop  NaN    A
2   G2   OK  NaN  NaN    B
3   G3  Sil  NaN  SLO    A
4   G4  NaN  NaN  NaN    C
5   G4  LIJ  KYI  NaN    B
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps simply:

```py
df.loc[df['COL2 COL3 COL4'.split()].isna().all(axis=1) & df['COL5'].isin({'A', 'B'}), 'COL2'] = 'OK'
```